Установить Ansible определенной версии на Debian
Как установить Ansible версии 2.17.3 на Debian 11?
Пробую стандартными способами:

Командой sudo apt install ansible
С помощью установки PPA-репозитория sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible

но в обоих случаях получаю версию Ansible 2.10, а мне необходима версия 2.17.3.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html

Пробовал такой командой: python3 -m pip install --user ansible-core==2.17.3, но ansible --version не дал результата, хотя процесс прошёл нормально. И ansible-playbook не отработал по скрипту.

А вы не забыли добавить локальный bin в PATH? Вроде pip должен был об этом предупредить

(ну и вообще лучше использовать виртуальное окружение, а не мусорить в глобале)

Ты ppa добавляешь в Debian? И какое же имя релиза у тебя добавляется?

Решил следующим способом:

Добавил ppa-репозиторий в систему (опционально).
Создал виртуальное окружение на основе Python v3.11.
Внутри окружения стандартно проинсталлировал Ansible командой python3 -m pip install --user ansible.

До этого устанавливал в окружение Python 3.9. Подозреваю, что по этой причине получал Ansible v2.10 вместо v2.17.3.
